# Remove linked games in Game Centre in iOS 15.3.1

Tags: ios, apple-id, games, game-center

I really want to unlink / delete the game data on my Game Centre and can’t seem to find a way of doing this.  I’m playing SimCity Build It and want to remove a city that’s linked in my Game Centre and it’s driving me nuts that I can’t find a simple way of removing this.

I’ve read previous questions on here and they all seem to refer to an older iOS version and not to the current version running (15.3.1) on an iPad Pro

I’ve raised a question on the Apple support page but haven’t had any answers so thought I’d raise a question here instead.

Comment: Give it a while, if you don't get an answer you could ask a moderator to migrate your question over to [Arqade SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).  Just don't cross-post to that site.

Comment: Sure thing, I’ll see if anyone suggests anything here first